# heroku restart - Does that result in data loss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Does using `heroku restart` result in data loss? Is the last DB backup used during a restart or is the DB unaffected?

Answer (score 6):

A restart does not affect the database. So, generally speaking, data loss will not occur on restart.

However, it will also restart your workers, which may interrupt any jobs currently being processed. This can result in a partially finished job, which may have an undesired effect, depending on the job. You should design any background jobs so they can be restarted from scratch if necessary (for instance, do any database interaction in a transaction).

A similar effect is also possible for your dynos - in this case, instead of a partially completed job, it would be a partially completed web request. This would very rarely cause a problem, though.

A deploy - but not necessarily a restart - will also cause any files in your temporary directories (`tmp/` and `log/`) to be deleted.

To prevent both of these, use maintenance mode (`heroku maintenance on`) and make sure all your workers and web requests are done working before you deploy or restart.

Comment: Thanks, that's strange. I'm noticing missing data on my app that was stored in the DB. The data appears to be going missing after heroku restart.

Comment: Are you caching data, e.g. with memcached? Could the view of the data been cached in your browser or Varnish?

Comment: No caching, no memcache. Just noticing after deployments data is going missing.

Comment: Well it's not possible for a restart alone to affect the database, so there has to be another explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to better monitor or gets logs that would show what happened to the records? Any 3rd party apps good for this?

Comment: I'd recommend `heroku addons:add logging:expanded` and setting your log level to `:debug`. You can then `heroku logs --tail` and see all the queries and other app activity.